# How to use multiple variables with geom_smooth in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just like the title, I want to use multiple independent variables in my model.

There is an easy example:

If I want to see the relationship between `mpg` and `disp`, I could use this:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = disp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x)
```

Then I want to see the relationship between `mpg` and `disp` adjusted `hp`, I write the below code occurring an error:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = disp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + hp)

# Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
# object 'hp' not found
```

Maybe I didn't mapping `hp` in `ggplot(aes())`, and I tried this but the same error occurring:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = disp, z = hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + z)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `color` or `size` in `aes()`

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = disp, color=hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x)
```

Yielding

[image]

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = disp, color=hp, size=hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]